# Proving: $\frac{2x}{2+x}\le \ln (1+x)\le \frac{x}{2}\frac{2+x}{1+x}, \quad x>0.$

Tags: inequality, induction, logarithms

$$\begin{equation}\frac{2x}{2+x}\le \ln (1+x)\le \frac{x}{2}\frac{2+x}{1+x}, \quad x>0\end{equation}$$

I found this inequality in this paper: http://ajmaa.org/RGMIA/papers/v7n2/pade.pdf (Equation (3)).

How exactly can I prove it? I tried induction but to no avail...

Comment: I guess it's (3) from the paper. You've rewritten it wrongly from the paper, it seems.

Comment: My bad. Corrected it.

Comment: The proofs seem not too difficult. Just observe the values for x=0, then (e.g. using derivatives) research the functions, show that one grows faster than the other. That's basically what `S.Panja-1729` suggests too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x) = \frac{2x}{x+2}$, $g(x) = \ln(1+x)$, $h(x) = \frac{x^2 + 2x}{2x+2}$.

$f(0) = 0$, $g(0) = 0$, $h(0) = 0$.

$f' = \frac{2(x+2)-2x}{(x+2)^2} = \frac{4}{(x+2)^2}$, $g' = \frac{1}{1+x}$, $h'= \frac{(2x+2)(2x+2)-2(x^2+2x)}{(2x+2)^2}=\frac{2x^2+4x+4}{(2x+2)^2}$

Now it is easy to check that
$$f'=\frac{4}{(x+2)^2} \leq g' = \frac{1}{1+x} \leq h'=\frac{2x^2+4x+4}{(2x+2)^2}$$

Comment: If they start from the same point a and f increases slower on some interval [a;b] than g which increases slower (on [a;b]) than h, it means that g will be between f and h on this interval. Try this by drawing graph of three random monotonic functions which start from the same point, but one is between other two and see connections between rate of growths of there functions.

Comment: see this graph > http://mathonweb.com/help_ebook/html/functions/functions61b.gif they all "start" from the same point and are monotonic consider their derivatives

Comment: Yup. Thanks a lot!

Comment: How do you prove that the functions in the original inequality are monotonous?

Comment: You can see that $f'$, $g'$, $h'$ are all above $0$ for $x>0$ so this means that all of them are strictly increasing.

Comment: But checking monotonicity in your inequality is not important, because derivatives already tell you that. I mentioned monotonicity so you can draw according graph.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint :**

Consider $$f(x)=\ln (1+x)-\frac{2x}{2+x}$$and $$g(x)=\frac{x(x+2)}{2(x+1)}-\ln(1+x)$$Show $f$ and $g$ are monotone increasing functions..

Comment: ... and then also use that f(0)  = g(0) = 0

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

I have a shorter proof: by the AM-GM inequality,
$$\forall t>0,\qquad \frac{1}{1+t}\geq \frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{t}{2}\right)^2}\tag{1} $$
as well as:
$$\forall t>0,\qquad \frac{1}{1+t}\leq \frac{1+(1+t)^2}{2(1+t)^2}.\tag{2}$$
Now it is enough to integrate both sides of $(1)$ and $(2)$ over $(0,x)$ to prove the statement.